# Auto resize of wxGrid

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, sizer

My wxWidgets program built with gcc and wxSmith has several sizers with texts and buttons, a wxMathPlot window and a wxGrid. When I chose something in a choice, the grid fills with a different amount of info and grows more rows if necessary or deletes the unecessary rows. As I start with 1 row, when the choice is made there is still one row displayed, but as soon as I touch the border of the window to resize it everything gets resized. The grid grows so that every row is displayed without scrollbars and the plot window grows or shrinks depending on how much space the grid leaves. Is there a possibility to code this behaviour, so it gets called everytime the grid gets new input?
I tried with

```
UserGrid->Fit();
SendSizeEvent();
```

at the end of the grid method, but this does not work.
I have a `OnResize()` method like following:

```
void Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnResize(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
    DoGetBestSize();
    UserGrid->Fit();
    //UserGrid->Refresh();
    Layout();

}
```

This is my layout (in case some of the settings I tried out creates the wanted behaviour)

```
 //(*Initialize(Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame)
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer4;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;
    wxFlexGridSizer* FlexGridSizer3;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxFlexGridSizer* FlexGridSizer5;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer2;
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer1;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxFlexGridSizer* FlexGridSizer6;
    wxMenu* Menu2;

    Create(parent, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE, _T("wxID_ANY"));
    SetClientSize(wxSize(525,713));
    Panel4 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL4, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL4"));
    BoxSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    BoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    LogFilePickerCtrl = new wxFilePickerCtrl(Panel4, ID_FILEPICKERCTRL2, wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFLP_FILE_MUST_EXIST|wxFLP_OPEN|wxFLP_USE_TEXTCTRL, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_FILEPICKERCTRL2"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(LogFilePickerCtrl, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(BoxSizer2, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    FlexGridSizer5 = new wxFlexGridSizer(0, 3, 0, 0);
    RadioButtonProe = new wxRadioButton(Panel4, ID_RADIOBUTTON4, _("PROE"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRB_GROUP, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_RADIOBUTTON4"));
    FlexGridSizer5->Add(RadioButtonProe, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    RadioButtonEng = new wxRadioButton(Panel4, ID_RADIOBUTTON5, _("ENG"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_RADIOBUTTON5"));
    FlexGridSizer5->Add(RadioButtonEng, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    RadioButtonUi = new wxRadioButton(Panel4, ID_RADIOBUTTON6, _("UI"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_RADIOBUTTON6"));
    FlexGridSizer5->Add(RadioButtonUi, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticText7 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("Label"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
    FlexGridSizer5->Add(StaticText7, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    ChoiceDate = new wxChoice(Panel4, ID_CHOICE3, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, 0, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_CHOICE3"));
    FlexGridSizer5->Add(ChoiceDate, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(FlexGridSizer5, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    FlexGridSizer6 = new wxFlexGridSizer(0, 3, 0, 0);
    StaticText10 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT20, _("Durchschnittlich genutzte Lizenzen \nam Tag"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT20"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticText10, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextDurchschnitt = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT21, _("Anzahl"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT21"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticTextDurchschnitt, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(-1,-1,1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticText12 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT22, _("Maximum genutzte Lizenzen"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT22"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticText12, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextMaximum = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT23, _("Anzahl"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT23"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticTextMaximum, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextMaximumTime = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT24, _("Wann"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT24"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticTextMaximumTime, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticText15 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT25, _("Minimum genutzte Lizenzen"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT25"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticText15, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextMinimum = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT26, _("Anzahl"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT26"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticTextMinimum, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextMinimumTime = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT27, _("Wann"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT27"));
    FlexGridSizer6->Add(StaticTextMinimumTime, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(FlexGridSizer6, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer4 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    MathPlot1 = new mpWindow(Panel4, ID_MATHPLOT2, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRAISED_BORDER|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
    xAxis = new mpScaleX(_("Time"), 1, true);
    MathPlot1->AddLayer(xAxis);
    yAxis = new mpScaleY(_("Licenses"), 4, true);
    MathPlot1->AddLayer(yAxis);
    VectorLicenses = new mpFXYVector(_("Licenses"), 0);
    VectorLicenses->SetContinuity(true);
    MathPlot1->AddLayer(VectorLicenses);
    VectorUser = new mpFXYVector(_("User"), 0);
    VectorUser->SetContinuity(true);
    MathPlot1->AddLayer(VectorUser);
    MathPlot1->UpdateAll();
    MathPlot1->Fit();
    BoxSizer4->Add(MathPlot1, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(BoxSizer4, 2, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    FlexGridSizer3 = new wxFlexGridSizer(0, 3, 0, 0);
    StaticText9 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT12, _("User\nFür Statistik Lizenz oben wählen"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT12"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticText9, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    ChoiceUser = new wxChoice(Panel4, ID_CHOICE2, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, 0, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_CHOICE2"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(ChoiceUser, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(-1,-1,1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticText4 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT13, _("Durchschnittliche Zeit \nLizenznutzung pro Tag"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT13"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticText4, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextStundenDurchschnitt = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT14, _("Betrag"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT14"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticTextStundenDurchschnitt, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticText1 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT15, _("Stunden"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT15"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticText1, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticText8 = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT16, _("Tag mit Stundenmaximum"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT16"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticText8, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextStundenMax = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT17, _("Stunden"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT17"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticTextStundenMax, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    StaticTextTagMax = new wxStaticText(Panel4, ID_STATICTEXT18, _("Tag"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT18"));
    FlexGridSizer3->Add(StaticTextTagMax, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(FlexGridSizer3, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    UserGrid = new wxGrid(Panel4, ID_GRID1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE, _T("ID_GRID1"));
    UserGrid->CreateGrid(1,5);
    UserGrid->EnableEditing(false);
    UserGrid->EnableGridLines(true);
    UserGrid->SetColLabelValue(0, _("Lizenz"));
    UserGrid->SetColLabelValue(1, _("Tag"));
    UserGrid->SetColLabelValue(2, _("Von"));
    UserGrid->SetColLabelValue(3, _("Bis"));
    UserGrid->SetColLabelValue(4, _("Nutzungszeit"));
    UserGrid->SetDefaultCellFont( UserGrid->GetFont() );
    UserGrid->SetDefaultCellTextColour( UserGrid->GetForegroundColour() );
    BoxSizer1->Add(UserGrid, 0, wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_LEFT|wxALIGN_TOP, 0);
    Panel4->SetSizer(BoxSizer1);
    BoxSizer1->Fit(Panel4);
    BoxSizer1->SetSizeHints(Panel4);
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);

    Connect(ID_FILEPICKERCTRL2,wxEVT_COMMAND_FILEPICKER_CHANGED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnLogFilePickerCtrlFileChanged1);
    Connect(ID_RADIOBUTTON4,wxEVT_COMMAND_RADIOBUTTON_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnRadioButtonProeSelect);
    Connect(ID_RADIOBUTTON5,wxEVT_COMMAND_RADIOBUTTON_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnRadioButtonEngSelect);
    Connect(ID_RADIOBUTTON6,wxEVT_COMMAND_RADIOBUTTON_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnRadioButtonUiSelect);
    Connect(ID_CHOICE3,wxEVT_COMMAND_CHOICE_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnChoiceDateSelect);
    Connect(ID_CHOICE2,wxEVT_COMMAND_CHOICE_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnChoiceUserSelect);
    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&Lizenz_Logfile_ReaderFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
```

Is there a way to get the window to resize so the grid is fully displayed?

---

Edit: As I found out while debugging, `OnResize()` never gets called when actually resizing the window. It has to be something done in the background, as I don't do anything else with my window size.

---

Edit 2: After trying quite a bit it seems that after using `UserGrid->AppendRow()` the grid does not repaint well. After this line a scrollbar that is visible beforehand disappears and only reappears if the window is resized by the user. I already tried `UserGrid->AdjustScrollbars()` followed by `UserGrid->ForceRefresh()` without effect.

Comment: How about using wxPanel? Gives you options of showing or hiding them and then all you need to call is `Layout`  and `Fit` functions of main window.

Comment: I tried Layout and Fit in several places but that did not have the expected outcome.

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_windowsizing.html, 
wxWidgets provides two main methods for sizing:

- wxWindow::Fit() sets the size of a window to fit around its children.
  The size of each children is added and then this parent window changes its
  size to fit them all.
- wxWindow::Layout() the opposite. The children will change their size,
  according to sizer rules, so they can fit into available space of
  their parent.  [...] is what is called by the default EVT_SIZE handler for container windows

Because a grid can have thousands of rows/cols its size can be huge. Don't try to tell the parent to fit around it. You better set max and min sizes for the grid (or its sizer) and then use Fit() or Layout() each time you change number of rows/cols or their sizes.

Comment: wxWindow::Fit() and wxWindow::Layout() does not seem to have effect here. I can add a max size for the wxGrid, but when there are too many rows to fit in the max size I am not able to generate a scrollbar without resizing the whole window manually per mouse. I tried `wxGrid::AdjustScrollbars()` and `wxGrid::ForceRefresh()` followed by `Fit()` or `Layout()`

Answer (score 0):

UserGrid->Fit(); works for me, but I have to use **no minimal size**. As there was set minimal size Fit() doesn't make any change. Also if size which was computed by Fit was bigger then preset minimal size, it doesn't change size. As I used default (-1) for minimal size it started to work.